# Install launch files cakin

Tags: ros, roslaunch, build, binary, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

folks,

How do I install launch files with catkin? I was trying the next code in my CMakeList.txt, but it was working:

```
## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
install(FILES
  ${PROJECT_NAME}/launch/my_launch_file.lunch
  # myfile2
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244777/install-launch-files-cakin/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-30**:
I assume you meant to write "but it wasn't working"?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-30**:
It's always a good idea to include any error messages or descriptions of unexpected/undesired behaviour. "it's not working" is too general, and we can't guess as to what didn't actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First (and I feel this is important): this is not a Catkin-specific problem or piece of functionality. The `install(..)` statement is part of regular CMake, and we just make use of it in our `CMakeLists.txt`. Only the `DESTINATION` argument has a Catkin-specific value, but `install(..)` would work with any path (it would just not install the launch files in the 'correct' (for ROS anyway) location).

As for your question: installing "launch files [or other resources]" (ie: not programs, libraries or headers) is documented on the ROS Wiki under [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt - Optional Step: Specifying Installable Targets - Installing roslaunch Files or Other Resources](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Installing_roslaunch_Files_or_Other_Resources):

> Other resources like launchfiles can be installed to `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}`:

> ```
> install(DIRECTORY launch/
> ```

```
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

The `PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE` only makes sense if you actually use Subversion as your VCS. In other cases you can leave it out.

Note that this installs an entire directory, which could not be what you want. Installing individual files is also possible, see the CMake documentation for `install(..)` for details.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4